# how to get class of a component or associations property from hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a hibernate mapping for student.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" 
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Student" table="STUDENT">
<id name="id" type="long" column="ID"/>
  <property name="name" column="NAME"/>
  <component name="address" class="Address">
    <property name="houseNumber" column="HOUSE_NUMBER" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="addrLine1" column="ADDRLINE1"/>
    <property name="addrLine2" column="ADDRLINE2"/>
    <property name="phone" column="PHONE"/>
  </component>
  <many-to-one name="organization" class="com.Organization" update="false" insert="false" fetch="select">
      <column name="ORGANIZATION_ID" not-null="true" />
  </many-to-one>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Please tell me how to get the class of the properties "address", "organization"

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @kelmer I want to write a java class which has a  name "organization" and I want to get the name of class i.e com.Organization  from the class meta data